# Device Orientation issue in iPhone/iPad iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my application i use both devices iPhone and iPad.Now the main problem is device orientation.i wanna use both portrait and landscape orientation.but i got this type of view when i rotate to right or left as below.

Also when i turned on autolayout option check then i also found new image like this.

[image: When turned on autolayout]

[image: This is original image]

[image: this when landscape]

i use firstViewController and also i put method for orientation and when i put breakpoint on it, it is not called and here is my code:

in fVC.m:

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            locationBtn.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,86,86);
           cameraBtn.frame  = CGRectMake(200,200,86,21);

        }

        else

        {

            locationBtn.frame = CGRectMake(200,200,86,86);
            cameraBtn.frame  = CGRectMake(230,200,86,21);
        }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check for auto layout, if its turned on then turn it off chk this http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/

Comment: @AmanAggarwal it is uncheck brother.

Comment: Rather than turning auto rotate off. set it on and set the autoresizing properly in xib you will not need to set the frame for orientation pragmatically.

Comment: Check my answer.. You have to set Autosizing and other properties...

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora ma'am please explain what u want to tell.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Properties]

Change in properties as per your need ..

You want to enlarge or you want to place elsewhere ..  ..

Comment: Yes, It is working because I am new and I have same problem..
Turn off autolayout from view and set from this properties..

Comment: i didn't use autoresizing ever please help....how to reduce size of image when landscape?

Comment: I think you know you have to put different images for iphone and ipad.. (@2x) and different forms..

Answer (score 0):

`-(BOOL)shouldRotate....`  Is no longer called as of iOs7.
Try moving this code to `-(void)didRotate..` Or 
(better, because your animations will sync with the built in ones)

```
-(void)willRotate...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enabling `Autolayout` doesn't add any constraints.

Select your items in .XIB and choose reset to selected constraints.

This might help you achieve what you are expecting.

I would recommend you learn and start using Autolayout. Quick link to help you get started:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo

**Change to do:**

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]